# Appending <div> to jQuery slider handle

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-slider

Is there any way I can append a div to the slider handle, so I can control the handle by dragging that div? Please see the picture attached.

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147387/tooltip-to-follow-jquery-slider-handle

Comment: Thanks for the reply... But it is div made up of separate divs. Unfortunately, It can't be replaced with tooltip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can attach a `<div>` to the handle and use that `<div>` to control the slider. The drag events work just as well on the handle's children as on the handle itself; so, you can just give the handle an appropriately absolutely positioned child, something like this:

```
// The actual selector would be a little more specific.
$('.ui-slider-handle').append('<span class="sidecar"></span>');
```

and some CSS:

```
/* The dimensions, position, ... are just examples, absolute positioning is the key. */
.sidecar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 0;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: #f00;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/9B4MC/